# How to import to a SQL Server table and start primary key where left off

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment, staging

I can't seem to find an answer to this. I am very new to SQL Server. I have been trying to set up a database to be updated daily for a website.

There is a `.CSV` file produced daily. I have set up a script to copy the file, edit the text and import the file into a table in SQL Server 2012.

There are 16 fields in the `.CSV` file. I have a 17th field in the table I import it into.
The 17th field is the Primary Key which I have set to `autoincrement`.

**My problem is this:**

I'm implementing this as a new process. This is already set up and in operation on an older server. The older server was using MySql. The Primary Key was left off at `81,720,024`.
I have set the Primary Key field to `autoincrement` with a seed of `81720024`.

Every time I update the table I truncate the table first and the import from a staging table. The Primary Key always starts at `81720024`. I need to have it increment from the last entry it had. Please help!

Comment: Thank you Jon, when executing the code directly inside of SQL Server there is no issue and the pk value is correctly incremented.

However, I have a new issue. I need to do this via my script. When I attempt to do this my script fails. It is a VBS error: 'Query timeout expired'

Comment: Line: 25, Char: 1, Error: Query timeout expired, Code: 80040E31

Here's a piece of my code:

21: strSQL = "DELETE FROM master.dbo.[importAccounts]" 
22: conn.Execute strSQL
23: strSQL = "BULK INSERT master.dbo.[importAccounts] FROM '"      : writeFile & "'" & _
24:          "WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )" 
25: conn.Execute strSQL

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting from the table instead of truncating.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to increase the 'CommandTimeout' property for my 'Connection String': conn.CommandTimeout = 300